# How to modify header font size in QTableView -- OSX-specific

Tags: macos, qt, fonts, qt5, qtableview

I am attempting to modify the size of the font used in the row and column headers for a [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) populated by a [QAbstractTableModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) in Qt5.4.0 on Mac OSX 10.9.5.

**UPDATE**: This seems to be an OSX-specific issue since I can run all three experiments below on CentOS 6.2 Linux with Qt5.4.0 and they all work just fine, producing the intended font-size changes.

For brevity I'll include all three experiments I've done [some of them inspired by StackOverflow and other blog postings...], labelled and commented out, in my sample code below:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QHeaderView>

class TestModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    public:
                        TestModel() {};
                        ~TestModel() {};

            int         rowCount( const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex() ) const;
            int         columnCount( const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex() ) const;
            QVariant    data( const QModelIndex& index, int role ) const;
            QVariant    headerData( int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role ) const;

};

int
TestModel::rowCount( const QModelIndex& index ) const {
    return 5;
}

int
TestModel::columnCount( const QModelIndex& index ) const {
    return 5;
}

QVariant
TestModel::data( const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const {

    switch( role ) {
    case( Qt::DisplayRole ):
            return( QString( "%1,%2" ).arg( index.row() ).arg( index.column() ) );
    default:
            return QVariant();
    }
}

QVariant
TestModel::headerData( int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role ) const {
    QFont   font;

    switch( role ) {
    case( Qt::DisplayRole ):
            if( orientation == Qt::Horizontal ) {
                    return( QString( "Column %1" ).arg( section ) );
            } else {
                    return( QString( "Row %1" ).arg( section ) );
            }
    // EXPERIMENT #3:
    // case( Qt::FontRole ):
    //      font.setPointSize(48);
    //      return font;
    default:
            return QVariant();
    }
}

int
main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    TestModel* model = new TestModel();

    QMainWindow* mw = new QMainWindow();

    QTableView* tableView = new QTableView();

    tableView->setModel( model );

    // EXPERIMENT #1:
    // QFont font;
    // font = tableView->horizontalHeader()->font();
    // font.setPointSize(48);
    // tableView->horizontalHeader()->setFont( font );

    // EXPERIMENT #2:
    // tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView { font-size: 48pt; }");

    mw->setCentralWidget( tableView );

    mw->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

When I run this without any font change attempts, or with EXPERIMENT #1, or with EXPERIMENT #2, I get the following:

[image: No EXPERIMENT, or EXPERIMENT #1, or EXPERIMENT #2 result]

Note that in the EXPERIMENT #1 and #2 results the font size for column and row headers has not changed, contrary to my hopes. When I run the code with EXPERIMENT #3 enabled I still get no change in the font size for column/row headers, though I do get the bizarre effect that the column-header boxes appear to be sized for the larger font:

[image: EXPERIMENT #3 result]

My preference would be to get a variant of EXPERIMENT #1 to work, which would harmonize better with the real code.

How can I successfully change the font size of the [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) row and column headers?

Comment: Which Qt version are you using? For me technically all 3 worked (maybe just needed `resizeColumnsToContents` to look better), I tested it on windows with `qt5.4.1`.

Comment: Qt5.4.0 on Mac OSX 10.9.5 -- I edited the question to reflect that. I retried EXPERIMENT #1, adding `tableView->resizeColumnsToContents()` after it, then reran and got the results of my second graphic -- high boxes for the column headers, but same size text.

Comment: I have the same problem on Qt 5.3.2. Any solution?